# Количество рекурсий

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def recursion(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else 1 + recursion(n - recursion(recursion(n - 1)))
 
print(recursion(int(input())))
```

Я написал код но он слишком долгий, можно как нибудь его ускорить?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы переиспользуете функцию, то можно кэшировать результат с помощью стандартной библиотеки python

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def recursion(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else 1 + recursion(n - recursion(recursion(n - 1)))
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

можно попробовать самому реализовать `lru_cache`

```
def lru_cache(func):
    dict_ = {}
    def wrapper(n):
        if n not in dict_:
            dict_[n] = func(n)
        return dict_[n]
    return wrapper

@lru_cache
def recursion(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else 1 + recursion(n - recursion(recursion(n - 1)))
```

Comment: Только это не `lru_cache`, ну, вернее, это аналог неограниченного кэша, такого же, впрочем, как использован за счёт параметра в другом ответе. Просто строго говоря, `LRU cache` должен "помнить" не все элементы, а только недавно использованные.

Comment: @CrazyElf это просто жалкая пародия на lru_cache

Comment: Короче, это кэш, но не `LRU`, извиняюсь за педантизм ))